# Вывод строки HelloWorld средствами С++

Tags: c++

Как интереснее всего написать `"Hello, world"` на C++?

Правила:

- Не использовать буквы для формирования текста.
- Не использовать функции вывода в консоль в явном виде.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212389/418910