# ХЕЛОВОРД КОНУКРС

Tags: c++, соревнование

Как прикольней всего написать HelloWorld на c++?
Конкурс!

не использовать буквы для формирования текста и не использовать функции вывода в консоль в явном виде

это другой ворос!!!